# Type casting used along with Compound assignment operator

Tags: c

```
((unsigned long long *)P)[0] += B;
```

Is the above Statement equivalent to: `((unsigned long long *)P)[0] = ((unsigned long long *)P)[0] + B;` ?

P is defined as: `int P[5];`

B is defined as: `unsigned long long B;`

Size of int is 2 bytes.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent? Equivalent in the way the instructions are interpreted or what the outcome of assembly code is? 
The results "in numbers" are the same.

Comment: @elasticman The way they are interpreted. Do they both mean the same thing? if they mean the same thing, I assume there won't be any difference in terms of assembly caode.

Comment: Note: You are dererencing pointer using the wrong type; that is *strict aliasing violation* and results in *undefined behaviour*. Both statements are invalid in standard C.

Comment: To expand on @user694733 comment and noting that in general `sizeof(int) != sizeof(long long int)`, see e.g. https://wandbox.org/permlink/CDb1VB3LcnUQ0DJj

Comment: To expand on @user694733's comment on strict aliasing, what you are doing is not guaranteed to work.  For example, on your system `int` could have a requirement to be aligned on a 2-byte boundary, while `unsigned long long` might have to be on an 8-byte boundary.  When you force an `int` to act as the start of an `unsigned long long` value, you violate your system's hardware restriction. If anyone posts "But it worked for me!", they're just showing that they don't understand what they're doing. A lot of people think what you're doing is OK because the common x86 systems mostly allow such code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle P is an array of Int, what is wrong if I type cast P as `unsigned long long`? how does it violates system's hardware restriction?

Comment: *P is an array of Int, what is wrong if I type cast P as `unsigned long long`?*  You can't do that because `P` is not an `unsigned long long`.  Period.  It's called the ["strict aliasing rule"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule)  What can happen?  [Most of these failures](https://www.google.com/search?q=sparc+SIGBUS) are probably caused by violating the strict aliasing rule on hardware that actually has alignment restrictions on data types.  Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880782/call-stack-shows-sigbus-what-does-that-mean

Comment: See [**6.3.2.3 Pointers**, paragraph 7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p7): "A pointer to an object type may be converted to a pointer to a different object type. If the resulting pointer is not correctly aligned for the referenced type, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @AndrewHenle There seems to be a small misunderstanding: Strict aliasing violation and alignment issue are not the same thing (although typical errors lead to both). You are right about alignment issues being hardware related. But it's possible to have SA violation even when alignment and size of types match. SA violation makes compiler blind to the changes in variable, so it may fail to insert instructions to refresh data between RAM and CPU register for example.

Comment: @user694733  Those were examples in response to the "how does it violates system's hardware restriction?" question a few comments up.  A strict aliasing violation without a hardware fault such as a `SIGBUS` could probably be described as "just more normal x86 code", for better or for worse.  The examples you mention - "fail to insert instructions to refresh data between RAM and CPU register" - are subtle bugs and hard to find common, clear-cut, and consistently-repeatable examples of, unlike searching for "SIGBUS arm" or "SIGBUS sparc".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They mean the same and the assembly (for x86-64 systems) is the same as well. You can check this at the godbolt compiler explorer [here](https://godbolt.org/z/HTS900) which shows the assembly of the two statements.

```
int P[5];
unsigned long long B;

void check1() {
    ((unsigned long long *)P)[0] += B;
}

void check2() {
    ((unsigned long long *)P)[0] = ((unsigned long long *)P)[0] + B;
}
```

Assembly of `check1`:

```
check1:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $P, %eax
        movq    (%rax), %rdx
        movq    B(%rip), %rax
        movl    $P, %ecx
        addq    %rdx, %rax
        movq    %rax, (%rcx)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Assembly of `check2`:

```
check2:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        movl    $P, %eax
        movq    (%rax), %rdx
        movq    B(%rip), %rax
        movl    $P, %ecx
        addq    %rdx, %rax
        movq    %rax, (%rcx)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        ret
```

Comment: Given `int P[5];`, `((unsigned long long *)P)[0] += B;` violates strict aliasing and is undefined behavior.  Such code will fail on systems that have alignment restrictions on data.  Like here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114491/structure-assignment-in-linux-fails-in-arm-but-succeeds-in-x86

Comment: My answer was limited to x86 systems and I have mentioned this in the answer.

Comment: [It's not guaranteed to work on x86 systems either.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15233717/disable-misaligned-data-fixups-on-x86-64-linux)

Comment: But would it not require the auto-alignment feature to be OFF for it not to work?